# Unexpected token error with Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, token, httparty

Attempting to execute the [basic.rb](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb) example for HTTParty. Running into an interesting error. Executing this under 1.8.7 on my Mac (10.7.2). When I run the example (see code below), I get this error:

```
$ ./HTTPartyTest.rb
./HTTPartyTest.rb: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./HTTPartyTest.rb: line 1: `dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))'
```

If I take line 1 and execute it via irb I get this result.

```
>> dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
=> "/Users/me/Workspaces/lib"
```

Not sure why this occurring. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../', 'lib')) give the same result? It did the same thing in irb here as without the slash.

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to add the correct hash-bang header or this will be executed using your shell instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# ... (Rest of program)
```

The alternative is to explicitly specify you want to run it with Ruby:

```
ruby ./HTTPartyTest.rb
```

Comment: This also solved an issue I had today with bin/rails (a custom one that took custom arguments). Same exact problem.